# Vault or safe? Which of the two nouns can have a connotation of a place where valuables were stored in ancient time?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word that gives a clear idea of a place where valuables were stored in ancient times. Both, vault and safe give a modern sense of storing valuables where the container is made of metal. Is there a word which is more rustic, basic, and less sophisticated than vault or safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [chest or a coffer](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chest_(furniture)) were used in medieval an Renaissance times  to store valuable items.

> - **A chest (also called coffer or kist)** is one of the oldest forms of furniture. It is typically a rectangular structure with four walls and a liftable lid, for storage. The interior space may be subdivided. **The early uses of an antique chest or coffer included storage of fine cloth, weapons, foods and valuable items.**

[Medieval chest](http://www.keeleyhire.co.uk/images/items/full/5677.jpg).

Comment: Coffer- most appropriate

Answer (score -2):

I would think that "crypt" would be a suitable replacement.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: Crypt is something very specific for burial places?

Comment: "Crypt" is certainly not a common modern word except in certain religious senses. Definitely has an aire of rough hewn stone holding something valuable.

Comment: What are you expecting to find there? Maybe that will help with the word suggestion.

Comment: I certainly expect to find valuables/coins/ jewels etc. It should be a place in a house where people can hide their wealth, much like burying coins in walls, used by commoners.

Comment: How about "chest"

Comment: If hewn out if the house itself a "crevice" or "chamber" might serve.